# Laravel Eloquent Model created_at to createdAt change is getting reverted

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to update the created_at and updated_at column names to my own custom values.

I understand that in order to change the column names I need to replace the const in the Model class for CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT.

I did this:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';
```

But it seems that whenever I make changes, and it is random, my changes are reverted back to:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';
```

My questions are two: Is there a better way to achieve this? And, why is this happening?

Comment: What file are you editing these in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are editing the `Model` class in vendor folder. When ever you do `composer update` its possible your changes will get override, therefore its not a good practice.

You have to add those constants in your model class. For example

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model {
    const CREATED_AT = 'createdAt';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updatedAt';
    ...
}
```